# How can I tell if a user is idle in Wayland?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x11, wayland

On X-Server based systems the utility xprintidle will return the number of milliseconds that the user has been idle.
Does similar functionality exist under Wayland?

I am attempting to write a small program that records application focus throughout the day, as a way to measure how I use my computer, productivity, etc.
I don't want the program to record activity when the machine is idle. Determining how long the user has been idle in X-Server sessions is easy with xprintidle, however this utility appears to be unmaintained, and does not function under Wayland.

The distros appear to be moving toward Wayland, for example the upcoming Ubuntu 17.10 uses Wayland by default, therefore xprintidle is no longer a workable solution.

Is there a mechanism in Wayland for determining if the user is idle, short of something inefficient like constantly polling for keyboard and mouse activity?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if there's an universal method, but for gnome-systems you can use this dbus call:

`dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor.GetIdletime`

Source: https://dev.gajim.org/gajim/gajim/issues/8839

Comment: Fantastic!  Will do more experiments later with different distros.